# Creating a superclass which will enable custom initialization from Dictionary for its subclasses

Tags: swift, design-patterns

#### What I have done:

I have several model classes, which have a variable number of attributes each. For example:

```
class A{
    var a1 : String
    var a2 : Int

    init(){...}
}

class B{
    var b1 : String
    var b2 : Int
    var b3 : AnyObject

    init(){...}
}
```

and so on. To initialize these classes from a `Dictionary`, I made a custom initializer with a `Dictionary` parameter and set each of the attributes like this

```
public class A{
    var a1 : String
    var a2 : Int

    public init(d : Dictionary<String,AnyObject>){
        if let value = d["a1"] as? String {
            a1 = value
        }else{
            a1 = ""
        }

        if let value = d["a2"] as? Int {
            a2 = value
        }else{
            a2 = 0
        }
    }
}
```

So, basically I am able to initialze the class `A` like so:

```
var objectOfClassA : A = A(d:["a1":"str", "a2":10])
```

If the `Dictionary` does not have a proper value corresponding to the key attribute of the class, it will just assign a default value to that attribute.

---

#### The problem:

In this implementation, my problem is that I will have to write the `init` method for each of the model classes that I want to create. My goal is to avoid writing the `init` method for every model class.

---

#### What I want to achieve:

Instead of writing the `init` method for each model class, I want to make a super class `Model` which will give a `Dictionary init` method like this to all its subclasses. So my `Class A` will look like this:

```
class A : Model{
    var a1 : String
    var a2 : Int
}
```

and still should initialize like before from a `Dictionary`.

I tried to use `Swift`'s reflection function to check the properties of the object being initialized, but I was not able to set the property from the dictionary. I guess the properties which can be seen by `reflect(self)[1]` are read-only. Please advise me on how to implement this type of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Tried this myself a while ago and haven't found a pure Swift solution.
However, if your base class inherits from NSObject you can always fall back using

`setValue("yourPropertyValue", forKey:"yourPropertyName")`